# "For + subj. + to" infinitive to indicate purpose

Tags: infinitives, for-to-complementizers

I would like more information about this type of construction. Good examples escape me at the moment, but it would be something along the lines of:

> These conditions need to be satisfied **for** this plan **to** be successful.

I only know of it because I've seen it in newspapers/heard it on TV. But I would like to know more. Specifically, what type of construction it is, other infinitives of the same kind or family, when it can/should/shouldn't be used, etc.

Basically, a page of a grammar textbook that mentions this construction is what I would like to see.

Comment: Your example is of a purpose adjunct consisting of a _to_-infinitival that contains a subject. It's the presence of an overt subject in a _to_-infinitival that makes the subordinator "for" obligatory. Another example might be "The casserole should be cooked very slowly (in order) for the beef to become succulent", where "in order" is optional.

Comment: Yes. _For_ is part of the infinitive complementizer; it marks the subject like _to_ marks the verb, but it's normally optional or disallowed, except when a subjectful infinitive begins a sentence, when it's required to indicate that the following clause is subordinate. One occasionally comes across a compound complementizer _for to_ in local speech or old songs; it's generally a marker for a purpose infinitive.

Answer (score 2):

From CaGEL p1178

> ### ***To*-infinitivals with and without subject**
>
> *To*-infinitivals with overt subject require the subordinator *for*
>
> *To*-infinitivals containing a subject are always introduced by the subordinator *for*:
>
> [20]
>
> i  [***For them*** to withdraw now] *would be a mistake.*  [subject]
>
> ii  *It's not been necessary* [***for them*** to wait any longer]. 
>   [extraposed subject]
>
> iii *The best plan would be* [***for them*** to go alone].
>   [predicative comp]
>
> iv *I can think of no solution except* [***for them*** to sack him].
>   [comp of preposition]
>
> If we drop the *for* we must also drop the subject, and conversely,
>   *for* cannot appear without a following subject. Compare [20ii], for example, with:
>
> [21]
>
> i *It is not necessary* [*to wait any longer*].
>
> ii  * *It is not necessary* [***them*** to wait any longer].
>
> iii * *It is not necessary* [***for*** to wait any longer].
>
> Notice, moreover, that the interrogative *to*-infinitivals shown in
>   [11i] and the *wh*- relative [11iia] cannot contain a subject:
>
> [22]
>
> i  a. *I can't decide* [***whether*** to go with them]. (=[11ia])
>
> b. * *I can't decide* [***whether (for) us*** to go with them].
>
> ii   a. *He doesn't know* [***how*** to placate her]. (=[11ib])
>
> b. * *He doesn't know* [***how (for) us*** to placate her].
>
> iii  a. *They have funds* [***with which*** to conduct a survey].
>   (=[11iia])
>
> b. * *They have funds* [***with which (for) us*** to conduct a
>   survery].
>
> The well-formed examples here all exclude *for* because the prenuclear
>   position is occupied - by the interrogative subordinator *whether*,
>   the interrogative phrase *how*, or the relative phrase *with which*.
>   And because an infinitival cannot contain a subject unless introduced
>   by *for* the asterisked examples here are as bad in the version
>   without *for* as in the one where *for* illicitly appears.

From CaGEL p1222-1223

> ### Adjunct of purpose
>
> In general, infinitival clauses functioning as adjunct of purpose are sharply distinct from catenative complements.
>   Syntactically, they can be preceded by *in order* and
>   characterisically can be moved to front position:
>
> [43]
>
> i *He walked* [*(in order) **to save money***].   [purpose adunct]
>
> ii [(*In order*) ***to save money***,]*he walked*.   [purpose adjunct]
>
> Semantically, they of course express the purpose of some agentive act
>   and we accordingly have a very clear ambiguity in:
>
> [44]  *He swore **to impress his mates***. [catenative complement or
>   purpose adjunct]
>
> The catenative interpretation is "He swore that he would impress his
>   mates (in some unspecified way)", whereas with an adjunct the meaning
>   is "He swore in order to impress his mates (by swearing)". In the
>   adjunct reading, *swore* receives greater phonological prominence and
>   in writing is likely to be followed by a comma.
>
> With a few verbs, sch as *wait* and *hurry*, the semantic distinction
>   is at times somewhat blurred - compare:
>
> [45]
>
> i.  a. *She was waiting **for his letter to arrive***. [catenative
>   complement]
>
> b. *She waited a while **to make sure he wasn't coming back***.
>   [purpose adjunct]
>
> c. *She was waiting **to use the photocopier***.
>
> ii. a. *He hurried **to reassure her***. [catenative complement]
>
> b. *He hurried, **to prove he wasn't as slow as she claimed***.
>   [purpose adjunct]
>
> c. *He hurried **to catch the train***.
>
> With *wait* the contrast is clear in [ia-ib]: the catenative
>   complement identifies the event she was waiting for and the adjunct
>   gives the purpose of her waiting; [ic] can be construed as a
>   catenative construction, but at the same time there is an element of
>   purpose. Presumably she couldn't use the photocopier immediately
>   (someone else was using it or it needed attention), so it was
>   necessary for her to wait. In [ii] *hurry* is equivalent to *hasten*
>   in [iia], wher the meaning is that he quickly reassured her, or tried
>   to do so; [iib] is straightforwardly purposive and readily allows *in
>   order* and fronting; such fronting is very unlikely in [iii], but it
>   is probably best treated as also purosive, for we could not here
>   substitute *hasten*.
>
> *Go* is a borderline member of the catenative category:
>
> [46]
>
> i *She went to the Old Vic **to see 'Hamlet'***. [purpose adjunct]
>
> ii *She went **to see 'Hamlet'***. [?catenative complement]
>
> It is quite clear that in [i] the phrase *to the Old Vic* is a
>   complement with the role of goal and the infinitival is an adjunct of
>   purpose. In [ii] (spoken without any prosodic break after *went*) the
>   concept of a spatial goal is very much backgrounded and it is not
>   implausible to regar the infinitival as having been reanalysed as a
>   complement: we certainly cannot insert *in order* and do not interpret
>   it as answering the question *Why did she go?*

Answer (score 0):

Using “for” or other related words like “in order to” communicate cause and effect. And yes, news story writers are notorious for writing like this as opposed to writing cause and effect events in temporal order with the conjunction “and”.

Using BillJ’s example and simplifying cause and effect.
The casserole should be cooked very slowly, and the beef becomes succulent.